# How to calculate a school year?

Tags: android, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to use this library of a calendar [TimesSquare](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) and I need to start the calendar by the next way:

```
Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
Date today = new Date();
calendar.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
    .withSelectedDate(today);
```

My problem is that I need to know a way to create a calendar that starts in september, and ends in august of the next year.

I need to do it automatically, I mean, If a user open the app in august, the calendar need to be from "September of 2013" to "August of 2014", But If the user open the app in September, the calendar should be from "September of 2014" to "August of 2015". I don't know If I explain me well, the interval of months will be the same every time, the year must changes, depending in the month you open the app.

How I can modify the previous code to achieve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just compare MONTH field of current calendar with AUGUST and then init calendars according to it. Smth like this:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) > Calendar.AUGUST) {
    // set "today" to september of current year and "nextYear" to august of the next one
} else {
    // set "today" to september of previous year and "nextYear" to august of the current one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to yunik to clear my mind. After that, I've had the next working idea.

```
Calendar today_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar start_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
        Date today = new Date();

        if (today_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) <= Calendar.AUGUST) {
            // set "today" to september of current year and "nextYear" to august of the next one
            int min_year = today_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1;
            int min_month = Calendar.SEPTEMBER;
            int min_day = 1;
            start_calendar.set(min_year, min_month, min_day);


            int max_year = today_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int max_month = Calendar.AUGUST;
            end_calendar.set(max_year, max_month, 1);
            int max_day = end_calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            end_calendar.set(max_year, max_month, max_day);

            calendar.init(start_calendar.getTime(), end_calendar.getTime()).withSelectedDate(today);
        } else {
            // set "today" to september of previous year and "nextYear" to august of the current one
            int year = today_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1;
            int month = Calendar.SEPTEMBER;
            int day = 1;

            // set "today" to september of current year and "nextYear" to august of the next one
            int min_year = today_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int min_month = Calendar.SEPTEMBER;
            int min_day = 1;
            start_calendar.set(min_year, min_month, min_day);

            int max_year = today_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1;
            int max_month = Calendar.AUGUST;
            end_calendar.set(max_year, max_month, 1);
            int max_day = end_calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            end_calendar.set(max_year, max_month, max_day);

            calendar.init(start_calendar.getTime(), end_calendar.getTime()).withSelectedDate(today);
        }
```

I hope this will help someone.